# LINQ Equivalent of SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm wanting to only display a list of CourseNo with no duplicates using LINQ, but I can't quite figure the syntax out.

```
        this.Distinct_CourseNo = (from c in Roster_Sections
                                  select c).Distinct(CourseNo).ToList;
```

The SQL equivalent would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CourseNo
FROM Roster_Sections
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the provided answers are applicable only if you have [moreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/). However, you can try this instead:

```
this.Distinct_CourseNo = (from c in Roster_Sections
                          group c by c.CourseNo into g
                          select g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

using `select c` will include all columns in the `Roster_Sections`, thus `Distinct()` will not work if atleast one row in a column is different from the other row.

```
this.Distinct_CourseNo = (from c in Roster_Sections
                          select c.CourseNo).Distinct().ToList();
```

or

```
this.Distinct_CourseNo = Roster_Sections.Distinct(c => c.CourseNo).ToList();
```

Comment: I get the following error using your Linq method provided: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Enrollment.Model.Sections>'

Comment: try, `this.Distinct_CourseNo = Roster_Sections.Select(c => c.CourseNo).Distinct().ToList();`

Answer (score 4):

You’d pass `Distinct` a lambda describing what defines distinctness:

```
this.Distinct_CourseNo = Roster_Sections.Distinct(x => x.CourseNo).ToList();
```

If you mean to get a list of unique course numbers as opposed to a list of unique courses based off course number, 今 草 顿 웃’s answer is the way to go.